# I think I saw something like a "net" outside of a ball while watching a football game, what was that?

Tags: football

I was watching a football game and I think I saw something like a web (or you may call it a net, like fish nets) outside of the ball.

It seemed odd, is there a thing like that in football?

Comment: Do you mean a small web of some string-like material around the ball itself? It may be just a printed pattern on the ball. A photo of something similar to what you saw would help.

Comment: It turns out that it is the thing you've just said, a pattern :)

Comment: @salep - If that's it, consider answering the question yourself and accepting it, so it doesn't show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by comments, the appearance of a net is just that: an appearance.

It is actually part of the printed pattern on the ball. One set of such balls is the Nike Ordem series:

[image: Nike Ordem 3 example]

Seen from a distance and in motion, it may well seem that the black lines are a net or strings around the ball. Other ball series from different producers may also have markings which, especially if not regular or symmetric, will give a similar appearance.